# Pulling the first number from a character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I've created the following function in SQL Server to pull a dollar amount out of a `varchar`. It looks for a dollar sign and then replaces any Ks or Ms with the appropriate amount of zeros. I've noticed that if there are other numbers in the `varchar` after the dollar amount (with or without a dollar sign) it will still pull it into the resulting number.

I want to modify this function to look at only the first number that appears in the string and ignore the rest.

Here's the function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION getNumericValue 
    (@inputString VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS 
BEGIN
     DECLARE @integerPart INT, @inputString2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

     SELECT @inputString2 = @inputString,
            @integerPart = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @inputString)

     WHILE @integerPart > 0
     BEGIN
         SET @inputString2 = STUFF(@inputString2, @integerPart, 1, '')
         SET @integerPart = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @inputString2)
     END

     IF TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, @inputString2) IS NOT NULL 
     BEGIN 
         IF PATINDEX('%$' + @inputString2 + 'k%', @inputString) > 0
         BEGIN
             SET @inputString2 = @inputString2 * 1000
         END

         IF PATINDEX('%$' + @inputString2 + 'm%', @inputString) > 0
         BEGIN
             SET @inputString2 = @inputString2 * 1000000
         END 
     END 

     RETURN ISNULL(@inputString2, 0)
 END
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails
(
    OrderID bigint UNIQUE,
    PaymentDetails varchar(200)
)


INSERT INTO OrderDetails
VALUES (27364829, 'Received $8,000')
       (47563892, 'Received $20K')
       (75372974, 'Received $2934.50')
       (56382753, 'Received $15k - no payment in 2021')
       (27464653, 'Will receive $5,000 over 5 years')
```

I've realized that the function also is not accounting for decimal places. The current output of the function on these five rows is the following:

```
8000
20000
293450
152021
50005
```

The desired output is:

```
8000
20000
2934.50
15000
5000
```

Comment: The snippet you've posted is not valid MySQL syntax, at least according to [the relevant documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/create-procedure.html), and therefore does not run or reproduce the issue you describe. Can you please verify that it is indeed a [mre] of the issue you're facing? Can you also take a look at the tags you've selected and make sure they're truly indicative of the specific SQL flavor with which you're working?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help (please include all edge cases). Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Why have you tagged [tag:regex]?

Comment: I've changed the mysql tag to sql-server, because the code you show is Microsoft SQL Server syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: This definitely needs a list of possible dollar strings so one can test anything

Comment: sample data has been added, let me know if anything else needs to be added - I also mistagged, I am using sql server not MySQL

Comment: `15k` should output `15000`? What should happen if you see `15.5k`? Do you also need to handle the ISO prefixes such as `da`, `h`, `M`, `G`, `T`, `P`, `E`, `Z`, `Y`, `R` and `Q`? What about the other ISO prefixes `d`, `c`, `m`, `μ`, `n`, `p`, `f`, `a`, `z`, `y`, `r` and `q`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, 15k should output 15000 and 15.5k should output 15500 but if I'm able to get the function to account for decimals then I'm thinking the current code could work for that. As for the prefixes, for this case we only need to account for k and M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat unoptimized and probably doesn't handle all the cases either, but here's my try:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION getNumericValue 
    (@inputString VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Get amount starting with $ and ending with space or whatever...
    DECLARE @dollar INT = PATINDEX('%$[0-9]%', @inputString)
    ,   @endDollar INT
    ,   @postfix INT
    ,   @result NUMERIC(19,2)
    IF ISNULL(@dollar, 0) = 0
        RETURN 0

    -- Find space or end...
    SET @endDollar = charindex(' ', @inputString, @dollar) - 1
    IF @endDollar = -1
        SET @endDollar = datalength(@inputString)

    -- get the string between dollar and end string
    SET @inputString = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@inputString, @dollar + 1, @endDollar - @dollar), ',', '')
    -- Multiplier
    SET @postfix = CASE RIGHT(@inputstring, 1) WHEN 'K' THEN 1000 WHEN 'M' THEN 1000000 ELSE 1 END
    -- Remove multiplier
    SET @inputString = REPLACE(REPLACE(@inputString, 'K', ''), 'M', '')

    -- Get the result result
    SET @result = ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(19,2), @inputString), 0) * @postfix
    -- Remove unnecessary decimals
    IF @result % 1 > 0
        RETURN CAST(@result AS NUMERIC(19,2))
    RETURN CAST(@result AS NUMERIC(19,0))
 END
```

Test code:

```sql
 SELECT x.*, dbo.getNumericvalue(n) AS result
 FROM   (
    VALUES (27364829, 'Received $8,000')
    ,   (47563892, 'Received $20K')
    ,   (75372974, 'Received $2934.50')
    ,   (56382753, 'Received $15k - no payment in 2021')
    ,   (27464653, 'Will receive $5,000 over 5 years')
    ,   (27464654, 'Will receive $ over 5 years')
    ,   (27464655, '$123,340')
    ,   (27464656, '')
    ,   (27464657, '$abc')
       ) x (id, n)
```

Output:

| id | n | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27364829 | Received $8,000 | 8000 |
| 47563892 | Received $20K | 20000 |
| 75372974 | Received $2934.50 | 2934.50 |
| 56382753 | Received $15k - no payment in 2021 | 15000 |
| 27464653 | Will receive $5,000 over 5 years | 5000 |
| 27464654 | Will receive $ over 5 years | 0 |
| 27464655 | $123,340 | 123340 |
| 27464656 |  | 0 |
| 27464657 | $abc | 0 |

Basic idea is to find the dollar and then find the next space or end of string and then work through that number. I've added some comments to the function explain the flow

Comment: this worked perfectly, I appreciate you! I'm seeing a few instances of where the dollar amount has parentheses around it, ex: ($30k) and the function isn't reading it and is returning 0 but I can play around with what you have to see if I can solve for this

Comment: You can probably just replace() with spaces in the function